# (Children's?) Movie where a man turns another man's heart into stone

Tags: story-identification, movie

My fiance watched a movie when she was a child that involved a man with a glove who turned another man's heart into stone.  She's pretty sure that it was a movie from the 1980s.

"Apparently, it was a fantasy-themed movie and the main character was a boy somewhere between 12 and 14 years old."

"Some bad guy had usurped... something.  And he had control over a lot of people because he had a glove that would turn people's hearts into stone."

We spent a fair bit of time searching, but the key terms are far too common for us to find anything on Google. Any help with the title or director or something would be appreciated.

Comment: In the movie, Kato never turns a heart to stone, but he does do that as his daily activity. He does have a metal hand and walks forward like he's going to do it to the boy, but that is at his very end.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wonder if you're thinking of the movie [**Mio in the Land of Faraway (1987)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mio_in_the_Land_of_Faraway) which is a fantasy with Nick Pickard as Mio / Bosse (left) and Christian Bale as Jum-Jum / Benke in the lead roles:

[image: Image of Mio and]

From Wikipedia

> From a whispering well, Mio learns that an iron-clawed knight from the Land Outside, Kato (Christopher Lee), has been kidnapping children and making them his servants by ripping out their hearts and replacing them with stone.

I know it says ripping, but [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093543/) says it got a Universal rating, which means this **definitely** wasn't shown on-screen and maybe either your fiancée or whoever wrote the summary assumed incorrectly from whatever is mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! We just went and watched a trailer for the movie and that's definitely it.
Now to go find a copy!